# Nginx domain.conf

Tags: nginx, config, symfony

Im web programming and I have always used Xampp in my projects. I want use a lemp server right now. 
I have deployed a lemp server (stack WTServer) and I have defined a domain.conf configured for Symfony. The problem is that root directive does not working.
Im watching the same content in **localhost/** and **domain.local/**.
The welcome page in the server (index.php).

This is my domain.conf:

```
server {
server_name metaenlaceerp.local;
root "c:/wtserver/www/metaenlaceerp";

## Access Restrictions
allow       127.0.0.1;
deny        all;

location / {
    # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
}
# DEV
# This rule should only be placed on your development environment
# In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass php_farm;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
# PROD
location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
fastcgi_pass php_farm;
    #fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include nginx.fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
    # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
    # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
    internal;
}

# return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
# this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
location ~ \.php$ {
  return 404;
}

error_log "c:/wtserver/log/metaenlaceerp_error.log";
access_log "c:/wtserver/log/metaenlaceerp_access.log";
}
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Added: **listen 127.0.0.1** and works.